# wordpress jetpack unwanted border in bootstrap email input

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, jetpack

I'm using the subscription form from Jetpack in Wordpress. I've Boostrappified the jetpack form as best I can with custom js, but can't seem to get rid of a pesky border - inside - the border provided by Bootstrap. The same thing appears on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (MacOSX) as well as iOS. How to get rid of this darn inner border?
[image: Unwanted border in email input field]

[Page illustrating the problem!](https://gurueap.com/reconstructing-trends/)

```
<div id="blog_subscription-2" class="widget widget_blog_subscription jetpack_subscription_widget">
    <h3 class="sidebar_title"></h3>
    <form action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="subscribe-blog-blog_subscription-2" class="input-group mb-3">
        <div id="subscribe-email" class="form-control">
            <label id="jetpack-subscribe-label" class="screen-reader-text" for="subscribe-field-blog_subscription-2">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="required" class="required" value="" id="subscribe-field-blog_subscription-2" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        <div id="subscribe-submit" class="input-group-append">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
            <input type="hidden" name="source" value="https://gurueap.com/reconstructing-trends/">
            <input type="hidden" name="sub-type" value="widget">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_fragment" value="blog_subscription-2">
            <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="3f90b6cdaf">
            <button type="submit" name="jetpack_subscriptions_widget" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please create a snippet or fiddle for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be resolved using below style

```
#subscribe-email input
{
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: add in customize css it will work

Check screenshot : https://www.screencast.com/t/HQMks9gwYtA

Comment: Ya I did the same through a 'Wordpress-enqueued' css file. Now working. It seems Wordpress wasn't happy that during development I wasn't using the enqueued file. Let that be a lesson to me and everyone else, I guess!

Answer (score -1):

```
#subscribe-email input {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d100;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: #686868;
    padding: 5px;
}
#subscribe-email{
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Above css is tested and worked